# Index match x 2?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am using the following index match formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!V:V,MATCH(Home!F16,Data!C:C,0)),INDEX(Contacts!E:E,Home!H16 & "*",Contacts!B:B,0))
```

I am trying to lookup a vlaue on sheet Data, and if the value is not found then look up the value on sheet contacts.

This always seems to be returning 0.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You are missing the MATCH on the second INDEX

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the MATCH on the second INDEX:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!V:V,MATCH(Home!F16,Data!C:C,0)),INDEX(Contacts!E:E,MATCH(Home!H16 & "*" ,Contacts!B:B,0)))
```

Comment: @user7415328 then one of your matches is finding a match and the return column is either empty or has a 0, otherwise it would error.

Comment: Could it be because 0 is not an error? And this is why the =IFERROR is not causing it to go to the second index match?

Comment: Yes, as I stated it is finding a match and returning the appropriate value, that just happens to be 0.  0 is not an error, if it were considered an error there would be a lot of false negatives.