# How do i add a 2nd Match criteria to Index(b:b,match(c2,a:a,0))

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am using excel and want help with using index(bb:,matchC2,a:a,0)) i want to add a second match criteria (first time user of Stackoverflow) - sample TAB_Y:Cell A2 Pear, a3 Apple, a4 orange, Cell b2  Red, b3 blue, b4 purple, Cell C2 'Yes", TAB Results: Column cell A2 Pear - desired result is 'Red

Comment: This doesnt work - INDEX(Tab_Y!$B:$B,MATCH('ResultTab'!$B2,Tab_Y!$A:$A,MATCH("yes",Tab_Y!$C:$D,0))) On Tab_Y i have 3 columns a- fruit, b - peal colour, c - 'yes' (as these are the ones i want (note the columns are text) and Results tab is the tab where i want the result eg 'red' if column C is yes. On results tab column b i have the fruit eg apples - hope i am not confusing the question

Comment: Rework your question rather than putting this relevant information in a comment.

Comment: Your index match in your question won't work... Is the example in the title correct?

Comment: Not sure, but will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42983962/4961700

Comment: as i said - it doesnt work - so i would like to find a way to add 2 match criteria to the index formula. i want to match what is in column A and column D while getting the text from column B (my mistake in the above $c:$d should read $d:$d)

Comment: I think you need to show some data that we can then see what you want in terms of a result, add it to the question.

Comment: TAB_Y:Cell A2 Pear, a3 Apple, a4 orange, Cell b2  Red, b3 blue, b4 purple, Cell C2 'Yes", TAB Results: Column cell A2 Pear - desired result  - hope this makes sense

Comment: nearly midnight here - will check for replies tomorrow - thank you for your support